# How to interpret "." as a variable and not as the placeholder using magrittr's forward-pipe operator

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I would like to create a `magrittr` pipe chain for the nested function call below 
which produces the exact same output.

The following returns a data frame with columns `my_names` and `Freq`.

```
my_names <- c('John', 'Joe', 'Jane', 'John', 'John', 'Jane')

test_df <- as.data.frame.table(sort(table(my_names), decreasing = TRUE))

   my_names Freq
1     John    3
2     Jane    2
3      Joe    1
```

Using `magrittr` the pipe chain below returns a data frame with columns `.` and `Freq`

```
library(magrittr)

test_df <- my_names %>% table %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame.table 

   . Freq
1 John    3
2 Jane    2
3  Joe    1
```

Adding `%>% dplyr::rename(my_names = .)` won't work because `.` is interpreted as the placeholder
and not as the column name.

To produce the same output as in the nested function call I need to use an additional function call: `test_df <- dplyr::rename(test_df, my_names = .)`

Is there a way to tell `%>%` to interpret `.` as a variable name and not as the placeholder in the subsequent call?

Comment: I get the same column names using pipes as I do with nesting (using the development version of dplyr).

Comment: @aosmith Thanks! When using the latest development versions of `dplyr` (0.3.0.9) and `lazyeval` (0.1.9.9001) the pipe chain produces the same result as the nested function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very, very late, but you can use the `rename_` version (with the underscore) and the *string* `"."`. This avoids nonstandard evaluation and hence works around `%>%` substituting `.`.

```
test_df <- my_names %>% table %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame.table %>%
    rename_(my_names=".")

#  my_names Freq
#1     John    3
#2     Jane    2
#3      Joe    1
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by @aosmith@ in the comments worked only for a couple of days.

The latest dev version 0.4 of `dplyr` also produces a data frame with the `.` column:

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/lazyeval")
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
library(dplyr)

my_names <- c('John', 'Joe', 'Jane', 'John', 'John', 'Jane')

my_names %>% table %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame.table

. Freq
1 John    3
2 Jane    2
3  Joe    1
```

My current solution now looks as follows and was suggested by docendo discimus earlier on:

```
my_names %>% table %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame.table %>%
  setNames(c('my_names', 'Freq'))
```